# How can I link my CSS class to my HTML file?

Tags: html, css, class

I am new to Web development and trying to create a basic avatar using **HTML/CSS.**

I created a style.css file, an `avatar.css` file and an index.html.

Everything works fine until I set the `.avatar` CSS class. I want to use it to round the corners of my image. But after I set the img class to "avatar", the images stay square while I should have 2 rounded images, one of **50x50ph** and the other of **30*30** (one being set to the class avatar and the other on the class avatar-small).

Here is what the page looks like:

[image: 1]

Here is my code

**CSS** ***style***

```css
/* --- Google Fonts--- */
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500;600&family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet")

/* --- Components Design--- */
@import "avatar.css";
/*@import url("components/button.css");*/
/*@import url("components/dropdown.css");*/
/*@import url("components/card.css");*/
/*@import url("components/badge.css");*/
/*@import url("components/banner.css");*/
/*@import url("components/tabs.css");*/
/*@import url("components/list.css");*/

/* --- Fonts--- */
body {
    font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica", "sans-serif"
}

h1, h2, h3 {
    font-family: "Montserrat", "sans-serif"
}
```

CSS *avatar*

```css
.avatar {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}

.avatar-small {
    border-radius: 30%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 30px;
}
```

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet'>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500;600&family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/73fba8f7d3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <title>Web Components</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container"> 
            <h1 class="text-center">UI components sprint</h1>
            <h2>Avatar design</h2>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="" class="avatar"> 
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="" class="avatar-small"> 
        </div>
        <!-- jQuery & Bootstrap JS for dynamic Bootstrap components -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I really can't understand what's wrong here. I tried finding the answer on my own but didn't manage to...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Will you please provide your folder structure? Where is your avatar.css located relative to your HTML document?

Comment: Hello! The 3 files avatar.css , style.css and index.html are all located in the same folder. I tried calling avatar with the full path as well as the relative path. Also, when I go over class="avatar" with my mouse in my HTML, a link to the .avatar class in my avatar.css appears, which means that the HTML recognises the class, , yes nothing is appearing...

Answer (score 1):

If you have linked the url of your image, and put `border-radius: 50%` properly, you should get the result.

What I find is that you've linked `style.css` 2 times, and missed out `avatar.css` external link file. If its typo, then fix it. Otherwise, you should get the result.

```css
img {margin: 20px;}
#img1 {border-radius: 10px;}
#img2 {border-radius: 30px;}
#img3 {border-radius: 50%;}
```

```html
<img id="img1" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
<img id="img2" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
<img id="img3" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First, check your developer tools to see if the file is loaded. if both files are in the same hierarchy level, it should be fine as your code seems to work.

Your CSS code misses some ";" at every rule, which might be the reason they're not applied. the fix should look like this:

```
.avatar {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}

.avatar-small {
    border-radius: 30%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 30px;
}
```

I hope it works, and happy coding :)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help. I just realised that 5 minutes ago and added the ";" . However, it still doesnt work! As answered just above, the three files are indeed in the same hierachy level.

Comment: well without seeing a live site / codepen it's very hard to assist you, maybe doublecheck the "network" tab or the css response to see that the files are actually rendering. 
and, see that the double css link in "head" doesn't create any errors.